# IBM Cloud: How do I see the newly attached block storage in a virtual server?

Tags: ibm-cloud, storage, block, disk, block-storage

I created a virtual server but found that the space was too small, so I wanted to add additional disk space to it. After attaching it, I'm not able to see the newly attached disk using `df -h` in the virtual server. How can I see the newly attached disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several commands that you can use: `fdisk -l` and `lsblk`.

The first disk drive should appear as `xvda`. Usually, there is a second disk drive `xvdb` that is used for swap. Your new disk will appear as `xvdc`. Note that naming is OS-specific.

You will need to partition the new disk, format a file system and then mount the file system to a directory. The exact steps are OS-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Following steps may change wrt OS. Below example specfic to [IBM VSI](https://www.ibm.com/sg-en/cloud/virtual-servers?p1=Search&p4=43700057917926788&p5=e&gclid=CjwKCAjw6qqDBhB-EiwACBs6x3Z2ShI9hNdcKJn6y23ZAzALpI4_D0wWv8kx-7lLjtIXfSZoJusZvhoCrxIQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) with `ubuntu 18.04 LTS`

First confirm the `disk` is attached to `VSI`(virtual server instance)and check the number of disk at the node by [fdisk](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fdisk.8.html) command.

```
fdisk -l | grep xvdc
```

Create a directory for new partition to be mounted

```
mkdir /data1
```

Make the partition using fdisk command

```
fdisk /dev/xvdc
```

After the above command it will ask some info

```
n  # And then hit enter until it creates the partition.
```

Format the partition using mkfs command [mkfs.ext4](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4)

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdc
```

[Mount](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) the partitoined on the new directory

```
mount /dev/xvdc /data1
```

Check the disk and its mounted points

```
df -h
```